# Cloudinary and React - Help me to add image url and corresponding image's folder to same object

Tags: reactjs, cloudinary

The upload I have done is successful
Help me to add image url and corresponding image's folder to same object after successful upload to Cloudinary.

```
- Parent folder
       - Children folder 1
             - image 1
             - image 2
             - image 3
             - ....
       - Children folder 2
             - image 1
             - image 2
             - image 3
             - .....
```

I will choose Parent folder to upload to Cloudinary, after downloading I want to put the image urls in the same object as Children folder 1, 2

The result I want when I'm done:

```
const images = [
        {
            folder: 'Children folder 1',
            image: ['image url 1','image url 2','image url 3','image url ....']
        },
        {
            folder: 'Children folder 2',
            image: ['image url 1','image url 2','image url 3','image url ....']
        }
    ]
```

Thank you very much

Comment: Generally, the image URL is returned in the [upload response](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_images#upload_response), so you should be able to grab and save it. Can you elaborate on how are you uploading the images? By folders, do you mean local folders? Or folders in Cloudinary? Please provide more context to your question.

Comment: Thank you very much, I have solved this problem